# display details of selected user in a list of users using drupal

Tags: javascript, php, html, drupal

I need to display details of selected user .I have done following code but that displays the details of all the user On click of a button

Created button using following code:

```
$form['button']['button_' . $result->full_name]= array(
    '#type' => 'button',    
    '#value' => $result->full_name,
    //'#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'javascript: table("login")'),
    //  '#attributes' => array('onclick' =>"table('login');"),
);
```

and created table using:

```
$form['table'] = array(
    '#theme'=>'table',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="login" style="display:none;">',
    '#suffix'=> '</div>',
    '#header'=>$header,
    '#rows'=>$rows,
);
```

where value of $rows is:

```
$rows[] = array(
    'sn_no' => $i,
    //'full_name' => $result->full_name,    
    'user_name' => $result->user_name,
    'role' => $result->user_group,
    'mobile' => $result->mobile,
    'email' => $result->email,
    // 'actions' => $manage_sid,    
    'actions' => "<a href='$base_url/?q=sf_user/edit_user/" . $result->user_id . "' style='margin-right: 6px;'><img src='$base_url/sites/default/files/images/edit.png' width='16' height='16'></a>
         <span onclick ='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal_" . $result->user_id . "' style='margin-right: 6px;'><img src='$base_url/sites/default/files/images/delete.png' width='16' height='16'></span>
             <a href='$base_url/?q=sf_user/view_user/" . $result->user_id . "' style='margin-right: 6px;'><img src='$base_url/sites/default/files/images/view.png' width='16' height='16'></a>
            <div class='modal fade' id='myModal_" . $result->user_id . "' role='dialog'>
                <div class='modal-dialog'>
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class='modal-content'>
                        <div class='modal-header'>
                            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                        <h4 class='modal-title'>Delete  User</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class='modal-body'>
                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete the SFA User " . $result->full_name . "?</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class='modal-footer'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' onclick='delete_user(" . $result->user_id . ");' data-dismiss='modal'>Ok</button>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           ",
);
```

javascript code is:

```
function table(id){
    var x =document.getElementById('login').rowIndex;
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";  
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```